# Regular expression compilation fail error

Tags: php, regex

regex  `'/^[0-9]{5}+\.[0-9]{3}+\.[0-9]{5}+(\.[0-9]{4}){4}/'`

string `00000.000.10115.0000.5210.9002.0000`

I think the regex that i created is wrong can someone correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple repeat is not valid. Drop `+` after `{..}`:

```
'/^[0-9]{5}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]{4}){4}/'
```

BTW, you can replace `[0-9]` with `\d`:

```
'/^\d{5}\.\d{3}\.\d{5}(\.\d{4}){4}/'
```

Comment: @ArunKillu, Surround the regular expression with delimiter. `'/^[0-9]{5}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]{4}){4}/'`

Comment: am sorry its bcoz code pad,i was learning pearl compatible regex.Thank you sir

Comment: @falsetru note that `\d` can match _any_ digit including, but not limited to 0-9 which includes Arabic numbers and such. I prefer to use `0-9` over `\d`.

Comment: @Class Point taken. But in PCRE, which PHP uses, `\d` only matches ASCII 0-9 by default even in UTF8 mode.